# Plotting two functions - one all the way to one point and other from that point on

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I know this QA is not for Wolfram alpha, but I really need help with plotting something. What I need to plot is one function until one point and other function but only from that point on. My attempt looks like this at the moment:

```
plot 10*x - 0.5 * 5 * x^2 for x=0 to 1.5 ,  -4*x + 0.5 * 5*x^2 + 10  for x=1.5 to 3
```

But it produces wrong results...

Comment: I think you need to use [Piecewise](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) but do not know W/ALpha myself.

Comment: Thank you. I will Google piecewise and see what I get.

Comment: I found the solution here thanks to you: http://whyseemath.com/wp/surveyofcalc/how-to-graph-a-piecewise-function-in-wolframalpha/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Wolfram|Alpha and questions about Wolfram|Alpha are explicitly excluded from this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it, it works on Alpha as is. It just did not like the `Exclusions -> None` but it still took it. Most of the times, Wolfram Mathematica language will also work in Wolfram Alpha as well. I like to think of it as the Wolfram Alpha language being an almost superset of the Wolfram Mathematica language.

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{10*x - 0.5*5*x^2, 0 < x <= 1.5}, 
   {-4*x + 0.5*5*x^2 + 10,1.5 <= x < 3}}],{x, -2, 5}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the Mathematica version that I tried first before porting to Wolfram Alpha:

```
Clear[x];
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{10*x - 0.5*5*x^2, 0 < x <= 1.5}, 
    {-4*x + 0.5*5*x^2 + 10, 1.5 <= x < 3}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 5}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]